# How to create a code object in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode

I'd like to create a new code object with the function types.CodeType() .
There is almost no documentation about this and the existing one says "not for faint of heart"
Tell me what i need and give me some information about each argument passed to types.CodeType ,
possibly posting an example.

**Note**:
In normal use cases you will just need the builtin function compile()
You should use types.CodeType() only if you want to create new instructions that couldn't be obtained writing normal source code and that require direct access to bytecode.

Comment: Why are you trying this?  It might be easier to accomplish via other means...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612449/what-are-the-arguments-to-the-types-codetype-python-call

Comment: FWIW, if it's not mentioned in the language reference, that means that the arguments it expects could be *implementation dependent*

Comment: One wouldn't normally directly run the constructor. Instead, one would write code (or construct an Abstract Syntax Tree from [AST nodes](http://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)), then use [compile()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#compile).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

–––––––––––
***Disclaimer*** :
Documentation in this answer is not official and may be incorrect.

This answer is valid only for python version 3.x

–––––––––––

In order to create a code object you have to pass to the function CodeType() the following arguments:

```
CodeType(
        argcount,             #   integer
        kwonlyargcount,       #   integer
        nlocals,              #   integer
        stacksize,            #   integer
        flags,                #   integer
        codestring,           #   bytes
        consts,               #   tuple
        names,                #   tuple
        varnames,             #   tuple
        filename,             #   string
        name,                 #   string
        firstlineno,          #   integer
        lnotab,               #   bytes
        freevars,             #   tuple
        cellvars              #   tuple
        )
```

Now i will try to explain what is the meaning of each argument.

**argcount**
Number of arguments to be passed to the function (*args and **kwargs are not included).

**kwonlyargcount**
Number of [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).

**nlocals**
Number of local variables ,
namely all variables and parameters(*args and **kwargs included) except global names.

**stacksize**
The amount of stack (virtual machine stack) required by the code ,
if you want to understand how it works , see official [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions).

**flags**
A bitmap that says something about the code object:
1 –>  code was optimized
2 –>  newlocals: there is a new local namespace(for example a function)
4 –>  the code accepts an arbitrary number of positional arguments (*args is used)
8 –>  the code accepts an arbitrary number of keyworded arguments (*kwargs is used)
32 –> the code is a generator

othes flags are used in older python versions or are activated to say what is imported from __ **future** __

**codestring**
A sequence of bytes representing bytecode instructions
if you want a better understanding , see [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) (same as above)

**consts**
A tuple containing literals used by the bytecode (for example pre-computed numbers, tuples,and strings)

**names**
A tuple containing names used by the bytecode
this names are global variables, functions and classes or also attributes loaded from objects

**varnames**
A tuple containing local names used by the bytecode (arguments first, then local variables)

**filename**
It is the filename from which the code was compiled.
It can be whatever you want,you are free to lie about this. ;)

**name**
It gives the name of the function.
Also this can be whatever you want,but be careful:
this is the name shown in the traceback,if the name is unclear,the traceback could be unclear,
just think about how lambdas can be annoying.

**firstlineno**
The first line of the function (for debug purpose if you compiled source code)

**lnotab**
A mapping of bytes that correlates bytecode offsets to line numbers.
(i think also this is for debug purpose,there is few documentation about this)

**freevars**
A tuple containing the names of free variables.
Free variables are variables declared in the namespace where the code object was defined,
they are used when nested functions are declared;
this doesn't happen at module level because in that case free variables are also global variables.

**cellvars**
A tuple containing names of local variables referenced by nested functions.

––––––––––––
***Examples*** :
following examples should clarify the meaning of what has been said above.

*Note*: in finished code objects attributes mentioned above have the **co_** prefix,
and a function stores its executable body in the **__code__** attribute

––––––––––––
*1st Example*

```
def F(a,b):
    global c
    k=a*c
    w=10
    p=(1,"two",3)

print(F.__code__.co_argcount)
print(F.__code__.co_nlocals , F.__code__.co_varnames)
print(F.__code__.co_stacksize)
print(F.__code__.co_flags)
print(F.__code__.co_names)
print(F.__code__.co_consts)
```

Output:

```
2
5 ('a', 'b', 'k', 'w', 'p')
3
67
('c' ,)
(None, 10, 1, 'two'. 3, (1, 'two', 3))
```

1. there are two arguments passed to this function ("a","b")
2. this function has two parameters("a","b") and three local variables("k","w","p")
3. disassembling the function bytecode we obtain this:

   ```
   3         0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)             #stack:  ["a"] 
             3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (c)             #stack:  ["a","c"]
             6 BINARY_MULTIPLY                            #stack:  [result of a*c]
             7 STORE_FAST               2 (k)             #stack:  []

   4        10 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)            #stack:  [10]
            13 STORE_FAST               3 (w)             #stack:  []

   5        16 LOAD_CONST               5 ((1, 'two', 3)) #stack:  [(1,"two",3)]
            19 STORE_FAST               4 (p)             #stack:  []
            22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)          #stack:  [None]
            25 RETURN_VALUE                               #stack:  []
   ```

   as you can notice chile executing the function we never have more than three elements in the stack (tuple counts as its lenght in this case)
4. flag's value is *dec* 67 = *bin* 1000011 = *bin* 1000000 +10 +1 = *dec* 64 +2 +1 ,so we understand that

   - the code is optimized(as most of the automatically generated code is)
   - while executing the function bytecode local namespace changes
   - 64? Actually i don't know what is its meaning
5. the only global name that is used in the function is "c" , it is stored in co_names
6. every explicit literal we use is stored in co_consts:

   - None is the return value of the function
   - we explicitly assign the number 10 to w
   - we explicitly assign (1, 'two', 3) to p
   - if the tuple is a constant each element of that tuple is a constant,so 1,"two",3 are constants

––––––––––––
*2nd example*

```
ModuleVar="hi"

def F():
    FunctionVar=106
    UnusedVar=ModuleVar

    def G():
        return (FunctionVar,ModuleVar)

    print(G.__code__.co_freevars)
    print(G.__code__.co_names)

F()
print(F.__code__.co_cellvars)
print(F.__code__.co_freevars)
print(F.__code__.co_names)
```

Output:

```
('FunctionVar',)
('ModuleVar',)
('FunctionVar',)
()
('print', '__code__', 'co_freevars', 'co_names', 'ModuleVar')
```

the meaning of the output is this:

first and second line are printed when F is executed,so they show co_freevars and co_names of G code:
"FunctionVar" is in the namespace of F function,where G was created,
"ModuleVar" instead is a module variable,so it is considered as global.

following three lines are about co_cellvars,co_freevars and co_names attributes of F code:
"FunctionVar" is referenced in the G nested function ,so it is marked as a cellvar,
"ModuleVar" is in the namespace where F was created,but it is a module variable,
so it is not marked as freevar,but it is found in global names.
also the builtin function print is marked in names , and all the names of attributes used in F.

––––––––––––
*3rd example*

This is a working code object initialization,
this is unuseful but you can do everything you want with this function.

```
MyCode= CodeType(
        0,
        0,
        0,
        3,
        64,
        bytes([101, 0, 0,    #Load print function
               101, 1, 0,    #Load name 'a'
               101, 2, 0,    #Load name 'b'
               23,           #Take first two stack elements and store their sum
               131, 1, 0,    #Call first element in the stack with one positional argument
               1,            #Pop top of stack
               101, 0, 0,    #Load print function
               101, 1, 0,    #Load name 'a'
               101, 2, 0,    #Load name 'b'
               20,           #Take first two stack elements and store their product
               131, 1, 0,    #Call first element in the stack with one positional argument
               1,            #Pop top of stack
               100, 0, 0,    #Load constant None
               83]),         #Return top of stack
        (None,),
        ('print', 'a', 'b'),
        (),
        'PersonalCodeObject',
        'MyCode',
        1,
        bytes([14,1]),
        (),
        () )

a=2
b=3
exec(MyCode) # code prints the sum and the product of "a" and "b"
```

Output:

```
5
6
```

Comment: Flag 64 appears to be `NOFREE` (according to output of `dis.code_info`).

Comment: [in core of python](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7ed7aead9503102d2ed316175f198104e0cd674c/Include/code.h) for anyone who wants to dig deeper.

Comment: Alberto, i've got a question when you wrote `co_code` element of your 3rd example. When you use `operation, listID, 0` in your *`bytes`* function did you use `listID,0` to emulate little endian or does `0` really stand for something ?

Comment: it seems that you have to fill in 16 arguments in types.CodeType with python 3.12

Answer (score 7):

Example usage of the CodeType constructor may be found in the standard library, specifically Lib/modulefinder.py.  If you look there, you'll see it being used to redefine the read-only `co_filename` attribute on all the code objects in a file.

I recently ran into a similar use case where I had a function factory, but the generated functions always had the "generic" name in the traceback, so I had to regenerate the code objects to contain the desired name.

```
>>> def x(): raise NotImplementedError
...
>>> x.__name__
'x'
>>> x.__name__ = 'y'
>>> x.__name__
'y'
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in x
NotImplementedError

>>> x.__code__.co_name
'x'
>>> x.__code__.__name__ = 'y'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute

>>> 'Gah!'
'Gah!'
```

But, wait, the function's `__code__` member is not read-only, so we can do what the modulefinder does:

```
>>> from types import CodeType
>>> co = x.__code__
>>> x.__code__ = CodeType(co.co_argcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount,
             co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize, co.co_flags,
             co.co_code, co.co_consts, co.co_names,
             co.co_varnames, co.co_filename,
             'MyNewCodeName',
             co.co_firstlineno, co.co_lnotab, co.co_freevars,
             co.co_cellvars)
>>> x.__code__.co_name
'MyNewCodeName'
>>> x()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in MyNewCodeName
NotImplementedError
```

The thing to note in this example is that the traceback uses the `co_name` attribute, not the `func.__name__` attribute when producing values in the stack trace.

One more note: The above is Python 3, to make it Python 2 compatible, just leave out the second argument to the constructor (`co_kwonlyargcount`).

UPDATE:  Victor Stinner added a new method, 'replace', to the CodeType class in Python 3.8, which simplifies the situation quite considerably.  This was done to eliminate future compatibility issues, as 3.8 also added a new 'co_posonlyargcount' argument into the call list after 'co_argcount', so at least your 3.8 and later code will be somewhat future proofed if the argument list changes again.

```
>>> x.__code__ = x.__code__.replace(co_name='MyNewCodeName')
```

Answer (score 3):

At the request of @KarlKnechtel, this answer is meant to supplement @AlbertoPerrella's answer with update-to-date (as of the time of this writing, for Python 3.11) information and documentation/sources of the `CodeType` constructor, the bytecode, and the new `CodeType.replace` method.

First of all, as the OP suggests, the official documentation for [`types.CodeType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType) is extremely limited, with no real signature:

> ```
> class types.CodeType(**kwargs)
> ```

So we have to piece together available information ourselves by looking at different but relevant sources.

For brief but reasonable explanations of all attributes of a `CodeType` object, we can find them in the `code` portion of the table in the [Types and members](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) section of the documentation for the `inspect` module.

However, that documentation has the attribute names listed in alphabetical order, rather than in the order the `CodeType` constructor expects them as positional arguments.

Since `types.CodeType` is defined in [`types.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f65497fd252a4a4df960da04d68e8316b58624c0/Lib/types.py#L14) as simply the type of the `__code__` attribute of an ad-hoc function, with no signature definition written Python:

```
def _f(): pass
CodeType = type(_f.__code__)
```

the only definitive way to obtain the real signature of `CodeType` is to look at its reference implemention in CPython, where all arguments are nicely validated in the [argument clinic](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f65497fd252a4a4df960da04d68e8316b58624c0/Objects/clinic/codeobject.c.h#L28) for the `code` constructor by their positions and expected types.

For example, from [this line](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f65497fd252a4a4df960da04d68e8316b58624c0/Objects/clinic/codeobject.c.h#L59):

```
argcount = PyLong_AsInt(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 0));
```

we can see that the first argument (position 0) is `argcount` as an `int` object because `PyLong_AsInt` is called.

And from [these lines](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f65497fd252a4a4df960da04d68e8316b58624c0/Objects/clinic/codeobject.c.h#L83):

```
if (!PyBytes_Check(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 6))) {
    _PyArg_BadArgument("code", "argument 7", "bytes", PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 6));
    goto exit;
}
code = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, 6);
```

we can see that the 7th argument (position 6) is `code` as a `bytes` object because `PyBytes_Check` is called, and ditto for the rest of the arguments.

Unfortunately, if we go through the arguments actually validated by the argument clinic, we'll notice some discrepancies with what's listed in the aforementioned `inspect` documentation, namely that the `inspect` doc is missing `co_linetable` and `co_exceptiontable`, and that the argument clinic no longer has the documented `co_lnotab`. With a quick search, we can find that per [PEP-626](https://peps.python.org/pep-0626/#the-co-linetable-attribute), `co_linetable` has replaced `co_lnotab`, which is now generated on-the-fly by the new `co_lines` method, and that per [issue 47236](https://bugs.python.org/issue47236), `co_exceptiontable` is now required to accompany `co_code` to hold exception handling information.

While issue 47236 helpfully points to the documentation of the format of `co_exceptiontable` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/exception_handling_notes.txt), PEP-626 on the other hand refrains from documenting the format of `co_linetable`, which it claims will remain "opaque":

> The `co_linetable` attribute will hold the line number information. The
> format is opaque, unspecified and may be changed without notice. The
> attribute is public only to support creation of new code objects.

But a look at the GitHub [changeset](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/877df851c3ecdb55306840e247596e7b7805a60a#diff-44732e29f0815b56b7fd64e8bead784b840294ed076595cd775ef71d1dc80df3) commited for an implementation of PEP-626 reveals that the format of `co_linetable` is actually well documented in [`lnotab_notes.txt`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/lnotab_notes.txt), and then later for Python 3.11, in [`locations.md`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/locations.md).

With all of the above pieces of information from various sources, we can now put together a full list of arguments in the positional order expected by the `CodeType` constructor, along with their types and descriptions:

| Position | Argument | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | co_argcount | int | number of arguments (not including keyword only arguments, * or ** args) |
| 1 | co_posonlyargcount | int | number of positional only arguments |
| 2 | co_kwonlyargcount | int | number of keyword only arguments (not including ** arg) |
| 3 | co_nlocals | int | number of local variables |
| 4 | co_stacksize | int | virtual machine stack space required |
| 5 | co_flags | int | bitmap of `CO_*` flags, read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect-module-co-flags) |
| 6 | co_code | bytes | string of raw compiled bytecode |
| 7 | co_consts | tuple | tuple of constants used in the bytecode |
| 8 | co_names | tuple | tuple of names other than arguments and function locals |
| 9 | co_varnames | tuple | tuple of names of arguments and local variables |
| 10 | co_filename | str | name of file in which this code object was created |
| 11 | co_name | str | name with which this code object was defined |
| 12 | co_qualname | str | fully qualified name with which this code object was defined |
| 13 | co_firstlineno | int | number of first line in Python source code |
| 14 | co_linetable | bytes | bytecode address-to-line information encoded in a format specified [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/locations.md) |
| 15 | co_exceptiontable | bytes | exception handling information encoded in a format specified [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/exception_handling_notes.txt) |
| 16 | co_freevars | tuple | tuple of names of free variables (referenced via a function’s closure) |
| 17 | co_cellvars | tuple | tuple of names of cell variables (referenced by containing scopes) |

As for the documentation of bytecode, we can find it nicely laid out in the [Python Bytecode Instructions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions) section of the documentation of the `dis` module, with the option to switch to the documentation for an earlier Python version with the drop-down menu at the top of the page, while the actual mapping of each bytecode to its respective integer value can be found in [`_opcode_metadata.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/_opcode_metadata.py).

Finally, although there has been an attempt to document the `CodeType.replace` method in [bpo-37032](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/17779), the end result in the official documentation of [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType.replace) is a very brief description with no examples:

> **replace(**kwargs)**
>
> Return a copy of the code object with new values for the specified fields.

Fortunately, we can find a good usage example in a unit test [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/34ddcc3fa118168901fa0d3a69b3b5444fc2f943/Lib/test/test_code.py#L196):

```
def new_code(c):
    '''A new code object with a __class__ cell added to freevars'''
    return c.replace(co_freevars=c.co_freevars + ('__class__',), co_code=bytes([COPY_FREE_VARS, 1])+c.co_code)
```

As can be seen, the usage of `CodeType.replace` is fairly straightforward, that all of the arguments that the `CodeType` constructor takes can be passed to the `replace` method with a direct replacement value. The idea is to eliminate the need to rebuild a new `CodeType` object with a long list of arguments from an existing `CodeType` object when only a few of the attributes need changed, so that code written for an older Python version does not need to be refactored when parameters are added to or removed from the `CodeType` constructor in a new Python version.

Hope this helps.