# Python setattr() to function takes initial function name

Tags: python, class, setattribute, setattr, dynamic-function

I do understand how `setattr()` works in python, but my question is when i try to dynamically set an attribute and give it an unbound function as a value, so the attribute is a callable, the attribute ends up taking the name of the unbound function when i call `attr.__name__` instead of the name of the attribute.

Here's an example:

I have a `Filter` class:

```
class Filter:
    def __init__(self, column=['poi_id', 'tp.event'], access=['con', 'don']):
        self.column = column
        self.access = access
        self.accessor_column = dict(zip(self.access, self.column))
        self.set_conditions()

    def condition(self, name):
        # i want to be able to get the name of the dynamically set 
        # function and check `self.accessor_column` for a value, but when
        # i do `setattr(self, 'accessor', self.condition)`, the function 
        # name is always set to `condition` rather than `accessor`
        return name

    def set_conditions(self):
        mapping = list(zip(self.column, self.access))
        for i in mapping:
            poi_column = i[0]
            accessor = i[1]
            setattr(self, accessor, self.condition)
```

In the class above, the `set_conditions` function dynamically set attributes (`con` and `don`) of the Filter class and assigns them a callable, but they retain the initial name of the function.

When i run this:

```
>>> f = Filter()
>>> print(f.con('linux'))
>>> print(f.con.__name__)
```

Expected:

- linux
- con (which should be the name of the dynamically set attribute)

I get:

- linux
- condition (name of the value (unbound `self.condition`) of the attribute)

But i expect `f.con.__name__` to return the name of the attribute (`con`) and not the name of the unbound function (`condition`) assigned to it.

Can someone please explain to me why this behaviour is such and how can i go around it?

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661758/name-of-a-python-function-in-a-stack-trace/40663943#40663943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function.__name__` is the name under which the function has been initially defined, it has nothing to do with the name under which it is accessed. Actually, the whole point of `function.__name__` is to correctly identify the function whatever name is used to access it. You definitly want to [read this for more on what Python's "names" are](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

One of the possible solutions here is replace the static definition of `condition` with a closure:

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, column=['poi_id', 'tp.event'], access=['con', 'don']):
        self.column = column
        self.access = access
        self.accessor_column = dict(zip(self.access, self.column))
        self.set_conditions()

    def set_conditions(self):
        mapping = list(zip(self.column, self.access))
        for column_name, accessor_name in mapping:
            def accessor(name):
                print("in {}.accessor '{}' for column '{}'".format(self, accessor_name, column_name))
                return name

            # this is now technically useless but helps with inspection
            accessor.__name__ = accessor_name
            setattr(self, accessor_name, accessor)
```

As a side note (totally unrelated but I thought you may want to know this), using mutable objects as function arguments defaults is [one of the most infamous Python gotchas](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) and may yield totally unexpected results, ie:

```
>>> f1 = Filter()
>>> f2 = Filter()
>>> f1.column
['poi_id', 'tp.event']
>>> f2.column
['poi_id', 'tp.event']
>>> f2.column.append("WTF")
>>> f1.column
['poi_id', 'tp.event', 'WTF']
```

EDIT:

> thank you for your answer, but it doesn't touch my issue here. My problem is not how functions are named or defined, my problem it that when i use setattr() and i set an attribute and i give it a function as it's value, i can access the value and perform what the value does, but since it's a function, why doesn't it return it's name as the function name

Because as I already explained above, the function's `__name__` attribute and the name of the `Filter` instance attribute(s) refering to this function are totally unrelated, and the function knows absolutely **nothing** about the names of variables or attributes that reference it, as explained in the reference article I linked to.

Actually the fact that the object you're passing to `setattr` is a function is totally irrelevant, from the object's POV it's just a name and an object, period. And actually the fact you're binding this object (function or just *whatever* object) to an instance attribute (whether directly or using `setattr()`, it works just the same) instead of a plain variable is also totally irrelevant - none of those operation will have any impact on the object that is bound (except for increasing it's ref counter but that's a CPython implementation detail - other implementations may implement garbage collection diffently).

Comment: Hi Bruno, thank you for your answer, but it doesn't touch my issue here. My problem is not how functions are named or defined, my problem it that when i use `setattr()` and i set an attribute and i give it a function as it's value, i can access the value and perform what the value does, but since it's a function, why doesn't it return it's name as the function name, i'd look into `setattr`. 

Also concerning using mutable objects as function args, i don't plan on updating/changing (appending) to these arguments, so i saw no harm here.

Thank you so much again.

Comment: @EmmanuelEvbuomwan cf my edited answer - TL;DR : I __did__ answer your question already.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you this :

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Filter:
    def __init__(self, column=['poi_id', 'tp.event'], access=['con', 'don']):
        self.column = column
        self.access = access
        self.accessor_column = dict(zip(self.access, self.column))
        self.set_conditions()

    def set_conditions(self):
        for i in self.access:
            setattr(self, i, SimpleNamespace(name=i, func=lambda name: name))

f = Filter()
print(f.con.func('linux'))
>>> linux
print(f.con.name)
>>> con
```

[edited after bruno desthuilliers's comment.]

Comment: Python has no pointer. `f.con` is actually an expression that evaluates as `getattr(f, "con")`, which in turn will evaluate to `f.__dict__["con"]`, which is a reference to the `method` instance created when evaluating `self.condition`, which method holds references to `f`, `Filter` and `Filter.__dict__["condition"]`.