# Patching an object by reference rather than by name string?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

The most common way to patch something in a module seems to be to use something like

```
from unittest.mock import patch

from mypackage.my_module.my_submodule import function_to_test

@patch('mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits.open')
def test_something(self, mock_fits_open)
    # ...
    mock_fits_open.return_value = some_return_value
    function_to_test()
    # ...
```

However, with the value passed to the patch decorator being a string, I don't get lots of the nice benefits from IDE. I can't use parts of the string to jump to definitions. I don't get autocomplete (and an implicit spelling check). Nor full refactoring capabilities. And so on.

Using `patch.object` I can get much closer to what I'm looking for.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import mypackage.my_module.my_submodule
from mypackage.my_module.my_submodule import function_to_test

@patch.object(mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits, 'open')
def test_something(self, mock_fits_open)
    # ...
    mock_fits_open.return_value = some_return_value
    function_to_test()
    # ...
```

However, this still requires the final part of the name of the referenced object is just a string. Is there a (nice) way to patch an object purely on the reference to that object? That is, I would like to be able to do something like

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import mypackage.my_module.my_submodule
from mypackage.my_module.my_submodule import function_to_test

@patch.reference(mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits.open)
def test_something(self, mock_fits_open)
    # ...
    mock_fits_open.return_value = some_return_value
    function_to_test()
    # ...
```

Comment: No, because ultimately objects aren't patched; names *referring* to objects are patched. `patch.object` is, in some sense, analogous to `getattr`. The first argument can be an arbitrary expression, but you still need the name of one of its attributes to actually patch.

Comment: This is essentially the same question as *[Can an object inspect the name of the variable it's been assigned to?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8875202/674039)* and the answer is basically no, names and objects live in different dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patching works by *replacing in the namespace where the name is looked up*.

The underlying logic of `mock.patch` is essentially working with a context-managed *name shadowing*. You could do the same thing manually with:

- save original value associated with name (if any)
- `try` overwriting the name
- execute the code under test
- `finally` resetting name back to the original value

Therefore, you fundamentally need to patch on a *name*, there is no patching a reference directly.

Comment: This seems to make sense. However, in my test function, I can do `tmp_open = mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits.open; mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits.open = Mock(); mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits.open.return_value = some_return_value; # Run test here; mypackage.my_module.my_submodule.fits.open = tmp_open`. And this accomplishes a similar setup and tear down using the reference alone. I'm guessing there's a reason why this wouldn't work in a more general decorator case?

Comment: It works because you used the name "open" by hardcoding it in your source code.  `mock.patch` will do more or less the same thing, but to offer that monkeypatch in a general way it needs to know how to resolve the name.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `__name__` attribute of the function object:

```
from unittest.mock import patch
import my_module

@patch.object(my_module, my_module.my_fun.__name__)
def test_something(self, mocked_fun)
    # ...
```

See also: [Name of a Python function in a stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40661758/name-of-a-python-function-in-a-stack-trace/40663943)

Comment: Hm... but why does this work, given the information from the other answer?