# Defining a function whose arguments are given by a list of strings

Tags: python, function, lambda, arguments, eval

I would like to define a function `make_function` that returns a new function. It takes as arguments a list `arg_names` of argument names for the new function and a function `inner_func` to be used in the definition of the new function.
The new function will just add 5 to the output of `inner_func` in this simple case.

I tried using `eval()`:

```py
def make_function(args_names: List[str], inner_func: Callable):
    args_str = str.join(", ", args_names)
    expr: str = (
        "lambda "
        + args_str
        + ": "
        + inner_func.__name__
        + "("
        + args_str
        + ") + 5"
    )

    return eval(expr)
```

This works.
But using `eval` is not recommended. For once, it is not easy to debug.
Also, in my use case I need to call the new function from a place where `inner_func` is not available, which raises an error.
Any other options?

Comment: It's possible, but it's really difficult. The problem is trivial if you use `*args`, so, why not just use `*args`? Does it really matter what the argument names are, if the only thing you will use them for is to pass them all, in the same order, into the `inner_func`?

Comment: There is also the operator module that can compose operations from constitutents.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.add for example.  And also [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).    Not sure if it fits your use case.  `eval` fits blackhats' use cases perfectly well however:  it is a massive security hole.

Comment: @wim Unfortunately the exact names of the arguments do matter: there is a function of a package I'm using which extracts the names of the arguments and builds a graph with those names as nodes (the details don't matter here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) is actually the best approach. `eval`/`exec` are usually not recommended *if the input string is arbitrary/untrusted*. However, when the code string which is eventually passed to the compiler was also generated by you, and not directly supplied by user, then it can be fine. There are some stdlib examples using this approach: [`namedtuple` uses `eval`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L434) and [`dataclass` uses `exec`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.0/Lib/dataclasses.py#L435), nobody has figured out how to exploit them (yet).

Now, I think that in your case it's fairly easy to do a safe code generation + exec simply by verifying that the `args_names` passed in is truly a list of arg names, and not some arbitrary Python code.

```
from textwrap import dedent
from typing import List, Callable

def make_function(args_names: List[str], inner_func: Callable):

    for arg_name in args_names:
        if not arg_name.isidentifier():
            raise Exception(f"Invalid arg name: {arg_name}")

    args = ', '.join(args_names)

    code_str = dedent(f"""\
        def outer_func({args}):
            return inner_func({args}) + 5
    """)

    scope = {"inner_func": inner_func}
    exec(code_str, scope)
    return scope["outer_func"]
```

Demo:

```
>>> def orig(a, b):
...     return a + b + 1
... 
>>> func = make_function(args_names=["foo", "bar"], inner_func=orig)
>>> func(2, 3)
11
>>> func(foo=2, bar=3)
11
>>> func(foo=2, bar=3, baz=4)
TypeError: outer_func() got an unexpected keyword argument 'baz'
>>> func(foo=2)
TypeError: outer_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'bar'
```

As desired, it continues to work even when a local reference to the `inner_func` is no longer available, since we made sure the reference was available *during code gen*:

```
>>> del orig
>>> func(foo=2, bar=3)
11
```

Nefarious "argument names" are not allowed:

```
>>> make_function(["foo", "bar", "__import__('os')"], orig)
Exception: Invalid arg name: __import__('os')
```

For an approach *without* using code generation, it is also possible to instantiate [`types.FunctionType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.FunctionType) directly. To do this you need to pass it a [`types.CodeType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.CodeType) instance, which are pretty difficult to create manually. These are public/documented, but the docstring for the code type even tries to scare you away:

```
>>> ((lambda: None).__code__.__doc__)
'Create a code object.  Not for the faint of heart.'
```

If you want to attempt it regardless, see [*How to create a code object in python?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16064409/674039) but I think you'll find that using `eval`, `exec` or `compile` is more convincing.

Comment: Thanks for a great, complete answer.
One question: I find it surprising that it still works after you delete `orig`. If I do the same with my code it doesn't work, as I said in the question statement. Does this have to do with `eval` vs `exec` or something else?

Comment: The difference is that you use `inner_func.__name__` in the lambda, so you're relying on the name binding. That name doesn't necessarily hang around. I'm using `scope = {"inner_func": inner_func}` so I pass the `inner_func` function instance itself. You can actually fix up the lambda approach by passing the second argument when you call `eval`, so that you are in control of the name lookup, but I think that using `exec` is cleaner and easier to understand here.

Comment: Note that using `inner_func.__name__` also creates another unnecessary restriction: you can't pass in a lambda as the `inner_func` callable, it's an "anonymous" function and you will get a syntax error in the `eval` (it doesn't have a usable `__name__` attribute). So use instead something like `eval(..., {"_inner_func": inner_func})` to control the name lookup in your version.