# How to compile Python code into byte code?

Tags: python, compilation, exec, bytecode

For example imagine I have myfile.py.
sample code:

```py
a = 6
b = 4
print(a+b)
```

So how can I convert this into bytecode?

I tried this:

```py
source_code = '''a = 6
b = 4
print(a+b)'''
compiled_code = compile(source_code, '<string>', 'exec')
print(compiled_code.co_code)
```

Result:

> b'\x97\x00d\x00Z\x00d\x01Z\x01\x02\x00e\x02e\x00e\x01z\x00\x00\x00\xa6\x01\x00\x00\xab\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00d\x02S\x00'

It does give me a bytecode, but when I run it using exec(), it results in this error.

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\Desktop\Python_projects\OBftestcode.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec(bytecode)
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

How can I hide the source code while exec bytecode?

Comment: How does`exec(bytecode)` not give you a NameError? You never defined `bytecode`...

Comment: `exec(compiled_code)` works just fine

Comment: If you need to work with the actual bytecode, there's e.g. [decompyle3](https://github.com/rocky/python-decompile3).

Comment: Only to mention it you can use jythonc to compile python files into bytecode

Answer (score 1):

Don't execute your result **bytecode**. Execute **compiled code** as an object returned by compile function like this:

```py
source_code = '''a = 6
b = 4
print(a+b)
''' # good style for using such functions as compile and others is to
#     write new line character at the end of the code
compiled_code = compile(source_code, '<string>', 'exec')
exec(compiled_code)
```

Do not execute `exec(compiled_code.co_code)`, as it contains byte code translated to viewable form, and doing this gives your error.

Comment: Ok. But I just want to hide the source code , so nobody can see it

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec and https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile

`exec(compiled_code)` will work just fine.

Were you trying to exec the string representation instead of the actual code_object by mistake?

Comment: So how can I just exec bytecode without showing the source code.

Comment: Not really sure why you would want to do this. But, seems you want to create a code_object that you can "exec" from raw byte codes rather than source code. You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064409/how-to-create-a-code-object-in-python. Not for the feint-hearted.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code:

```html
import codecs

source_code = '''a = 6
b = 4
print(a+b)'''

compiled_code = compile(source_code, '<string>', 'exec')

# Convert bytecode to hexadecimal representation
bytecode_hex = codecs.encode(compiled_code.co_code, 'hex')
print(bytecode_hex)
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Actually the `exec(compiled_code)` already works fine.