# How to compose functions through purely using Python's standard library?

Tags: python, functional-programming, standard-library, language-features, function-composition

Python's standard library is vast, and my intuition tells that there must be a way in it to accomplish this, but I just can't figure it out. This is purely for curiosity and learning purposes:

I have two simple functions:

```py
def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def double(x):
    return x * 2
```

and I want to compose them into a new function `double_and_increment`. I could of course simply do that as such:

```
double_and_increment = lambda x: increment(double(x))
```

but I could also do it in a more convoluted but perhaps more "ergonomically scalable" way:

```
import functools

double_and_increment = functools.partial(functools.reduce, lambda acc, f: f(acc), [double, increment])
```

Both of the above work fine:

```py
>>> double_and_increment(1)
3
```

Now, the question is, is there tooling in the standard library that would allow achieving the composition **without any user-defined lambdas, regular functions, or classes.**

The first intuition is to replace the `lambda acc, f: f(acc)` definition in the [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) call with [`operator.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.call), but that unfortunately takes the arguments in the reverse order:

```
>>> (lambda acc, f: f(acc))(1, str)  # What we want to replace.
>>> '1'
>>> import operator
>>> operator.call(str, 1)  # Incorrect argument order.
>>> '1'
```

I have a hunch that using `functools.reduce` is still the way to accomplish the composition, but for the life of me I can't figure out a way to get rid of the user-defined lambda.

Few out-of-the-box methods that got me close:

```py
import functools, operator

# Curried form, can't figure out how to uncurry.
functools.partial(operator.methodcaller, '__call__')(1)(str)

# The arguments needs to be in the middle of the expression, which does not work.
operator.call(*reversed(operator.attrgetter('args')(functools.partial(functools.partial, operator.call)(1, str))))
```

Have looked through all the existing questions, but they are completely different and rely on using user-defined functions and/or lambdas.

Comment: what's wrong with the highest voted answer in the question marked as duplicate? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24047214/671543)

Comment: @njzk2 It defines `compose2`, which in turn uses a `lambda`. I want to "abuse" the language and only use existing definitions from the standard library.

Comment: I considered it a duplicate because it lists over a dozen ways to accomplish what you want. Choose whichever one is closest to your needs. If there were a built-in way to do exactly what you want, it would be in there.

Comment: Your restrictions seem arbitrary, and basically what I'm saying with that closure is "Sorry, it's not possible."

Comment: @Barmar I've seen people do some pretty crazy stuff with Python. Very hard to imagine there isn't a ridiculously convoluted expression of stdlib functions that could achieve this. Of course no one would have added that as an answer to the "duplicate" question, since it would be laughable to use than in a real codebase. My restrictions are complex for learning purposes. I'm also willing to add a bounty to this after 2 days have passed.

Comment: If you don't want a lambda, nothing prevents you from definition a function instead, I'm not sure I get it. Are you asking if there is a function that compose functions already defined?

Comment: @njzk2 I'm looking to find a function (or more likely, a bunch of functions knotted together) from the standard library and builtins that would replace the need to define any new named functions or lambdas.

Comment: looks like you'd need a way to _compose_  `reverse` and `call`, in order to use call, which, if you can compose those, you can compose anything, so it's a bit of a  chicken and egg problem

Comment: @njzk2 Exactly. It seems so close, but still so far away. I'm still 95% sure that some Python guru will come up with a hack for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer of mine I don't agree that the test suite discovered by @AKX should be considered as part of the standard library per the OP's rules.

As it turns out, while researching for an existing function to modify for my other answer, I found that there is this helper function [`_int_to_enum`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a430b4ffdd9b8f32e53140e4d4450691d980c0c9/Lib/signal.py#L24) in the `signal` module that perfectly implements `operator.call` for a callable with a single argument, but with parameters reversed, exactly how the OP wants it, and is available since Python 3.5:

```
def _int_to_enum(value, enum_klass):
    """Convert a numeric value to an IntEnum member.
    If it's not a known member, return the numeric value itself.
    """
    try:
        return enum_klass(value)
    except ValueError:
        return value
```

So we can simply repurpose/abuse it:

```
from signal import _int_to_enum as rcall
from functools import reduce, partial

def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def double(x):
    return x * 2

double_and_increment = partial(reduce, rcall, [double, increment])
print(double_and_increment(1))
```

This outputs:

```
3
```

Demo: [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZAxDsIwEAR7v-JKG0IRKoTESxCyTGKDJedsXc5SeAtNGvgTH6EmSggUcO2Odm_3ek8XPkfs-1tmt9o8no5iA60_oQngmxSJQXtkzVFbzA2YFqgyIYgRdBkrjjG0M0u2zpUtIBlib4IQtXXgsSLbWGTZqa2A4chyJoQOllBOTB3zMdhfYAHrARhFbbDWHy_YzSFyDh0fK2A_4cU396BEoqGF_GckS6Wm9u8R5jFe)

Comment: Haha, nice. Now I'm wondering whether there's a nice [ast-grep](https://ast-grep.github.io/) pattern that could find all gadgets like this...

Comment: Haha indeed we could do that to much more efficiently find a particular code pattern we desire.

Comment: Okay, this is *nice*. Even though it's unexported, `_int_to_enum ` is still way more inherently part of the standard library than the other two (nevertheless great) answers.

Comment: But it is more readable to use the onliner: `compose = lambda *fs: reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), fs)` and use: `double_and_incrmeent = compose(increment, double)`

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Yes a user-defined function is the most obvious way to do this, but the OP artificially adds the rule to prohibit user-defined functions and classes apparently for fun and out of curiosity.

Answer (score 7):

Well, since you're saying

> I want to "abuse" the language and only use existing definitions from the standard library

[starting with Python 3.12, the test suite happens to contain the gadget you want](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/test/test_zipfile/_path/_functools.py):

```
import functools
import operator
from test.test_zipfile._path._functools import compose

increment = functools.partial(operator.add, 1)
double = functools.partial(operator.mul, 2)
increment_and_double = compose(increment, double)
print(increment_and_double(10))
```

(I found this by way of a strategic `ag compose` in my local CPython checkout.)

Comment: Wouldn't have guessed it would be this easy, thanks!

Comment: So, a seemingly useful function is only available through a long chain of underscored import meant for testing? It seems this would be a good addition to the existing `functools`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I disagree. Without OP's artificial limitation for not defining anything oneself, this is just `def compose(fa, fb): return lambda x: fa(fb(x))`...

Comment: Fully agree that the standard library does not need this.

Comment: While it is cool that you've found an out-of-the-box function that perfectly implements the functionality that the OP desires, it is hardly part of Python's standard library, for reasons I have detailed in my answer.

Comment: I have a small doubt. why should one expect everything being available in P-standard library. According to my understanding, python standard library is an additional feature given to simplify the job. But it doesn't mean that we can do everything with P-std Library. When one is comfortable with basic algorithm and data structures, Why should  he/she need to search for the same in std library? That too when direct approach is simpler than the other. For eg., when we can write as a**2, why should we unnecessarily import math module and write math.pow(a, 2).

Comment: @SuramuthuR one wouldn't. The question was purely for curiosity. One should definitely not constrain themselves to the standard library in any real task.

Answer (score 4):

While it is cool that @AKX found the function `test.test_zipfile._path._functools.compose` in the CPython code tree that perfectly implements the OP's desired functionality of function composition, it does not actually belong to the *standard library* as required by the rules of the question, for reasons that:

- It belongs to a helper module in a *test suite* of the *CPython* implementation of the Python language.
- A test suite is *not* part of the standard library of the language; it is just code that validates a particular implementation of the language and its standard library.
- A test suite, let alone any helper functions within the test suite, may be removed at any time without any normal due process of advanced deprecation warnings.
- Other implementations of Python does not need to include any of CPython's test suite in order to conform to Python's specifications.

So, without the helper function in the test suite of CPython 3.12 that is not part of the standard library, I believe the OP is indeed correct in the assessment that there is no out-of-the-box tooling in Python's standard library that can implement function composition.

BUT, that doesn't mean we can't achieve it by ***modifying*** existing tooling, since the OP's rules are simply to use "tooling in the standard library that would allow achieving the composition **without any user-defined lambdas, regular functions, or classes"**.

Since the OP almost got it already with:

```
double_and_increment = partial(reduce, lambda acc, f: f(acc), [double, increment])
```

and:

```
>>> (lambda acc, f: f(acc))(1, str)  # What we want to replace.
>>> '1'
>>> import operator
>>> operator.call(str, 1)  # Incorrect argument order.
>>> '1'
```

The real question here is then how we can *modify* an existing function in the standard library such that it becomes:

```
def rcall(value, obj):
    return obj(value)
```

To do that, let's take a look at the bytecode of the above function, as well as relevant attributes of the code object that defines the parameters:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def call(value, obj):
...     return obj(value)
...
>>> dis.dis(call)
  1           0 RESUME                   0

  2           2 PUSH_NULL
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (obj)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (value)
              8 PRECALL                  1
             12 CALL                     1
             22 RETURN_VALUE
>>> c = call.__code__
>>> c.co_varnames
('value', 'obj')
>>> c.co_argcount
2
>>> c.co_nlocals
2
>>>
```

No surprise there. A simple function body that loads the second argument (`obj`) and the first argument (`value`) onto the stack, then make a call with the callable and the argument in the stack, and finally returns the value at the top of the stack to the caller.

Now, let's find a similarly simple function in the standard library that takes an argument or two and make a call with it/them, so it can more easily be modified into our desired function. As it turns out, [`operator.abs`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a430b4ffdd9b8f32e53140e4d4450691d980c0c9/Lib/operator.py#L71) is one such function, which takes one argument and makes a wrapper call to the built-in `_abs` function:

```
def abs(a):
    "Same as abs(a)."
    return _abs(a)
```

We'd want to disassemble it for comparison, and yet unfortunately, if we try accessing `operator.abs.__code__`, you would get an error:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.abs.__code__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__code__'. Did you mean: '__call__'?
>>>
```

This is because CPython's implementation of the `operator` module includes an `_operator` module, which overrides all of the `operator.py`'s pure-Python functions with ones implemented in C, wit a `try` block in [`operator.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/289af8612283508b67d7969d7182070381b4349b/Lib/operator.py#L413):

```
try:
    from _operator import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Functions implemented in C do not have `__code__` objects and therefore cannot be modified. What we need is the [pure Python version](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/289af8612283508b67d7969d7182070381b4349b/Lib/operator.py#L226) of `operator.call`, before it's overridden by `_operator.call`. But how do we avoid the override? Well, we can import `_operator` module ourselves first and and delete the `call` attribute from it so that the modified module is cached in `sys.modules` such that when `operator.py` imports `_operator`, it is our modified version that it gets, without `call` in it:

```
>>> try: # other Python implementations may not have _operator.py
...     import _operator
...     del _operator.call
... except ImportError:
...     pass
...
>>> import operator
>>> operator.call.__code__
<code object call at 0x000001F68F4FADB0, file "C:\python311\Lib\operator.py", line 226>
```

Great! Now we can finally get to look at the bytecode and relevant attributes of the code object of `operator.abs`:

```
>>> dis.dis(operator.abs)
 71           0 RESUME                   0

 73           2 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (NULL + _abs)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
             16 PRECALL                  1
             20 CALL                     1
             30 RETURN_VALUE
 71           0 RESUME                   0
>>> c = operator.abs.__code__
>>> c.co_varnames
('a',)
>>> c.co_argcount
1
>>> c.co_nlocals
1
>>>
```

As can be seen, all we need to modify to turn `operator.abs` into our desired function object is to replace the `LOAD_GLOBAL` instruction into `PUSH_NULL` (to indicate a regular function call for [`CALL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL)) and `LOAD_FAST 1` (to load the second argument, the callable), as well as `co_varnames`, `co_argcount` and `co_nlocals` to add a second parameter `obj`.

To obtain a modified code object from the existing code object of `operator.abs` we can call its [`replace`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77155447/6890912) method:

```
try:
    import _operator
    del _operator.abs
except ImportError:
    pass
from operator import abs as rcall
from opcode import opmap
from functools import partial, reduce

code = bytearray(rcall.__code__.co_code)
code[code.find(opmap['LOAD_GLOBAL']):code.find(opmap['LOAD_FAST'])] = \
    opmap['PUSH_NULL'], 0, opmap['LOAD_FAST'], 1
rcall.__code__ = rcall.__code__.replace(
    co_code=bytes(code),
    co_varnames=('value', 'obj'),
    co_argcount=2,
    co_nlocals=2
)
print(rcall(1, str))
```

This correctly outputs:

```
1
```

So it then becomes trivial to implement the composite function that the OP wants, by plugging in the modified `operator.call` into the OP's close attempt:

```
def increment(x):
    return x + 1

def double(x):
    return x * 2

double_and_increment = partial(reduce, rcall, [double, increment])
print(double_and_increment(1))
```

This outputs:

```
3
```

Demo: [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bVLLTsMwEJQ4-iv2lgRMRXtCSDkU8ZQqQIKeqspynQ0EOba1capW4k-4cIGP4mtwnYaKRw5RtDOzM5vd1w-39k_WvL29t748PP7ce_G0PmEQnqp2ljwI65CktxSLBepdZSAXDcOVQufhOrLPiSx1ciebhpVka-jpfcegAtkAKal1z1C2wB63rpauA8rWKG-tbnrMSfKV1BwIi1YhY1GYw2LtURLJdRrbDoTYAEIMlI1fWSTONq9BWZkijSazZHI7PhOXk9vT8SSZZyf_4xfj-4eAzoPPtnw3vb8SN9NJEHE44vCXzWHIfkYJ6l_ZCJ2WCtP4v7ZB880kTRoz8x5YSjKyxiZPk6XULSYcErt4TnYMSY_Ktsbno--S0TbYNfmIZYwVWEJlFGGNxqerrNsRoW_JwAoOQtrIKWy70PiXsA-jQIigkKYQ373CVNudpN1KeDclh1lH5zvfecYcVcH_v0bpMMu6I9zeYn-TXw)

Comment: Excellent hack too, great job! I was thinking about futzing around with bytecode, but didn't feel like it was necessarily worth it. The concerns around portability between versions (where a gadget in `test` may or may not exist) still exist here – I don't think there's any compatibility guarantees for bytecode.

Comment: Agreed. I guess my main point is simply that my approach uses only toolings from what I consider to be the standard library.

Comment: Is this for Python 3.11? I think `PRECALL` got removed in 3.12: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/103910/files, and running this on it causes `KeyError: 'PRECALL'`.

Comment: @ruohola Indeed `PRECALL` is removed in 3.12. I've updated my answer so that it uses a function more similar to our desired function as a starting point to modify from so that the code can be compatible with 3.12. Also added a separate answer with my new finding.